# Incorrect charset in broken base64

Tags: php, character-encoding, base64, ipb

I am trying to decode this type of coded base64 in PHP:

```
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
```

Web tools like [base64decode.org](https://www.base64decode.org) can do that when I set encoding as `utf-8` but how to that in PHP?

When I try with `base64_decode()`, the charset is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I tried and it was decoded sucessfully.
I did it in the following way.

<?php 
echo base64_decode("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");
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the fresh perspective it was a problem with charset in database and web page. I lost many hours thinking it's a problem with the base64 encoding.